# Wordpress - Allow Query Strings

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I'm having issue in our wordpress website in passing query strings that we need in our
google analytics. Is it possible to pass Dynamic GET parameters on wordpress and do nothing if the value does not mean anything on the website instead of having 301 Redirects?

```
example.com/hello/world/?dynamic_param=trackingcode1234
```

As much as possible we would like to avoid installing new plugins for this, but if cannot be avoided is there any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Replace this on yout .htaccess then try, before replace take a backup.

For more refer [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: is it possible to apply this using add_rewrite_rule in wp-includes/rewrite.php instead of htaccess file? thanks